# ifconfig command on mac does not show IP address

Tags: networking, unix, ip, ip-address, ifconfig

When I run `ifconfig`, `eth0` is not shown, and only `en0` is displayed:

```
>> ifconfig en0 | grep inet
inet 192.168.0.102 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

When I type `My IP` in Google, my IP address is `50.143.137.xxx`.

Why I cannot find my IP address from `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macs are based on BSD, not linux, so there are some differences. in this case, [bsd](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1445465?start=0&tstart=0) uses 'enX' for interface names, instead of 'ethX'.

As for the IP address, @Big Perm is correct, your router (or your ISP's hardware) is using [NAT](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm) to translate your local address into a public IP address, which is what google sees.

Answer (score 2):

The IP address listed in ifconfig is that applied to the network adaptor itself. The differing IP address present on your Google search is most likely due to Network Address Translation configuration on your router/firewall translating your RFC1918 source IP to the "WAN" or "public" IP address provided by your ISP.

Comment: ok.. then how do we use `ifconfig` [or other tool] to view the public IP address?